# ASP .NET(4.5) MVC byte[] file retrieval from database difficulties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day, I am having a great deal of difficulty retrieving a simple byte array from my database for download. I am well aware of how to achieve this, and as far as I can tell, have all of my bases covered; yet cannot locate the file in the relative path. 
DesignModel:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string ContentName { get; set; }
}
```

The data and metadata save perfectly fine so I know that the creation is not an issue, it is only my retrieval that has an issue.
View Models:

```
public class MessageAdd
{
    //..
    public HttpPostedFileBase Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class MessageBase : MessageAdd
{

    public MessageBase()
    {
        url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string ContentName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }

    private string url = "";
    public string AttachUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/image/Message/Attachment{1}", url, Id);
        }
    }

}
```

Message Controller:

```
private Manager m = new Manager();
    // GET: Message
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Inbox()
    {
        return View(m.Inbox());
    }
```

Manager class inbox fun:

```
public IEnumerable<MessageBase> Inbox()
    {
        var messages = ds.Messages.Where(x => x.Recipient == uNm);

        return (messages == null) ? null : Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MessageBase>>(messages);
    }
```

File Controller:

```
private Manager m = new Manager();

    [Route("image/Message/Attachment/{id}")]
    public ActionResult GetMessageLogoById(int? id)
    {
        // Determine whether we can continue
        if (!id.HasValue) { return HttpNotFound(); }

        // Fetch the object, so that we can inspect its value
        var fetchedObject = m.GetMessageById(id.Value);

        if (fetchedObject == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            // Return a file content result
            // Set the Content-Type header, and return the photo bytes
            return File(fetchedObject.Attachment, fetchedObject.ContentType, fetchedObject.ContentName);
        }
```

GetMessageByID( in manager ):

```
public MessageBase GetMessageById(int id)
    {
        var fetchedObject = Mapper.Map<MessageBase>(ds.Messages.Find(id));

        return (fetchedObject == null) ? null
            : fetchedObject;
    }
```

the view:

```
//..
        <th>
            Attachment
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    //.. 

        @{
            if (item.ContentType != null)
            {
                if (item.ContentType.Contains("audio"))
                {
                    <td>
                        <audio controls>
                            <source src="@item.AttachUrl" type="@item.ContentType">
                            Audio playback not supported.
                        </audio> <br />
                        <a href='@item.AttachUrl' download> Download audio</a>
                    </td>
                }
                else if (item.ContentType.Contains("video"))
                {
                    <td>
                        <video width="300" height="280" controls>
                            <source src="@item.AttachUrl" type="@item.ContentType">
                            Video playback not supported.
                        </video> <br />
                        <a href='@item.AttachUrl' download> Download video</a>
                    </td>
                }
                else if (item.ContentType.Contains("image"))
                {
                    <td>
                        <a href='@item.AttachUrl' download>
                            <img src='@item.AttachUrl' alt="@item.ContentName" title="@item.ContentType" style="width: 100px;" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        <a href='@item.AttachUrl' download>File - @item.ContentType</a>
                    </td>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No Attachment.</td>
            }
        }
    //..
    }@
```

I have actually achieved results with this method on another project and when I compare the two I cannot see any difference in my logic. Any light shed would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve]. That's a lot of code to ask people to read through...

Answer (score 0):

Your **AttachUrl** returns wrong url. There is no "/" before "{1}".

```
public string AttachUrl
{
    get
    {                                                   // here
        return string.Format("{0}/image/Message/Attachment/{1}", url, Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the catch. unfortunately it did not resolve my issue :(